# Specifying multiple simultaneous output formats in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to be able to specify multiple output formats at the same time, for instance html_document and a pdf_document.  I know that this can be done very simply with something like

```
---
  output: [html_document, pdf_document]
---
```

I might have some of that syntax off, but I can not seem to find the documentation anywhere.  I have recently discovered knitr-bootstrap and love it.  It is what I have been looking for to be able to dynamically hide my code and output blocks.

Unfortunately, by default, the YAML block for the knitr-bootstrap invocation is quite complex and I do not know how to specify multiple outputs for this.

I have looked at the YAML spec and tried a few different things but I am at a loss.  Below is my current YAML frontmatter.

```
---
title: "Beta Regression Comparison"
opset: bootstrap
output:
  knitrBootstrap::bootstrap_document:
    title: "Beta Regression Comparison"
    theme: Simplex
    highlight: Solarized - Light
    theme.chooser: FALSE
    highlight.chooser: FALSE
    menu: FALSE
  pdf_document
---
```

Comment: This Quarto documentation provides good examples for what you trying to do:  https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/authoring/rstudio.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The solution is to change `pdf_document` to `pdf_document: default`. I can't unfortunately find a reference for this syntax in the official documentation. If however you open a RMarkdown document in a recent version of RStudio, click `Knit HTML` and then `Knit PDF`, it uses this `: default` syntax.

The syntax is:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
  pdf_document: default
---
```

Comment: Its just a limitation of yaml - output needs to be a named list, and you can't create a named element with no content

Comment: Yes, true. I wasn't able though to find a reference or example for the `default` keyword in the `rmarkdown` documentation.

Comment: thanks, I find have been looking for this. I don't find the knitr header to be so intuitive.

Comment: The flag for keep_md is no longer "yes" but "true". (so: `keep_md: true`). See the documentation: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html

Answer (score 4):

In my case,  I tried to knit multiple output-documents using bookdown and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662365/knit-one-markdown-file-to-two-output-files/53280491#53280491) which allowed me to get the desired result.

You can write the output-definition in your YAML header as follows:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    template: "path-to-my-template"
  bookdown::word_document2:
    default
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding){
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding,
  output_dir = "my-output-path", output_format = "all") })
---
```